# How does pair contract know that a caller of swap is the one who sent it coins just before calling swap?

Tags: solidity

I've spent many days just studying the lower level functions, and I can't see where is the piece of code in the `swap` functions that makes pairs actually KNOW the surplus of tokens is coming from the caller (there is no mapping *anywhere*). It performs self calls, which - if the system worked in real time, would be vulnerable to countless exploits.

If it doesn't know address X sent it tokens Y but instead calls `self.balanceOf()` and `self.getReserves()` to verify that, I have a natural question - how can this work, where is the code that makes this work, because between execution of all those lines of code (depending on the code robustness of who's calling the swaps) maybe the balances/reserves already changed? Where is the mapping?

Example function `swap` for your convenience:

```
function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external lock {
    require(amount0Out > 0 || amount1Out > 0, 'ApeSwap: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT');
    (uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1,) = getReserves(); // gas savings
    require(amount0Out < _reserve0 && amount1Out < _reserve1, 'ApeSwap: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');

    uint balance0;
    uint balance1;
    { // scope for _token{0,1}, avoids stack too deep errors
    address _token0 = token0;
    address _token1 = token1;
    require(to != _token0 && to != _token1, 'ApeSwap: INVALID_TO');
    if (amount0Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token0, to, amount0Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
    if (amount1Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token1, to, amount1Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
    if (data.length > 0) IApeCallee(to).pancakeCall(msg.sender, amount0Out, amount1Out, data);
    balance0 = IERC20(_token0).balanceOf(address(this));
    balance1 = IERC20(_token1).balanceOf(address(this));
    }
    uint amount0In = balance0 > _reserve0 - amount0Out ? balance0 - (_reserve0 - amount0Out) : 0;
    uint amount1In = balance1 > _reserve1 - amount1Out ? balance1 - (_reserve1 - amount1Out) : 0;
    require(amount0In > 0 || amount1In > 0, 'ApeSwap: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT');
    { // scope for reserve{0,1}Adjusted, avoids stack too deep errors
    uint balance0Adjusted = balance0.mul(1000).sub(amount0In.mul(2));
    uint balance1Adjusted = balance1.mul(1000).sub(amount1In.mul(2));
    require(balance0Adjusted.mul(balance1Adjusted) >= uint(_reserve0).mul(_reserve1).mul(1000**2), 'ApeSwap: K');
    }

    _update(balance0, balance1, _reserve0, _reserve1);
    emit Swap(msg.sender, amount0In, amount1In, amount0Out, amount1Out, to);
}
```

Does it clone the state of the blockchain? How is there no collusion in time? If 100 people send transactions nanoseconds after one another, shouldn't the self.balance calls get bunch of those surplus values at once and give incorrect calculations? Yet, the system works. I don't know how.

I don't see it in the code.

Follow-up question: if it doesn't clone state, how do calls to let's say IERC20(coin_external).balanceOf() work, since they might be busy and indulged in their own swaps not able to simulate a bazillion simulations.
Thus, if it clones the state - who's paying for it happening? For the countless estimations? Where does it happen and can I see that code?

Comment: Transactions are never executed in parallel. I suggest learning how the blockchain works before delving into smart contracts.

Comment: Can you point to the whole contract? In similar AMMs they don't really care who is the sender, they only care about the current contract state. It is up to the caller to protect themselves, implementing some type of reentrancy protection. In any case RiccardoS is correct in that transaction are processed sequentially so different transactions cannot interfere with each other.

Comment: @Ismael : My question is more akin to: "if at nanosecond n caller1 calls swap(), and then at nanosecond n+1 caller2 calls swap(), and pair contract calls its self calls for caller1 at n+4 and for caller2 at n+5, why doesn't there occur collusion with both reads accumulated?" Funds were pre-sent. Clearly, since it works SOMEHOW a separate call-environment has to be provided for both callers, despite of the timing, right?! And it works with self calls, but it's unfathomable... Without mapping, how can the pair successfuly isolate environments for each caller, preventing such exploits?

Comment: @tommy1213 In Ethereum blockchain there aren't concurrent transactions, they are processed in sequential order. T1 is completed before T2, and so on. Usually there is a router contract that manages several token pair. The router funds a token pair and calls the swap function atomically in a single transaction.